# How can I center a relatively sized element in an Android app?

Tags: android, element, center, android-relativelayout

If I am using:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:background="@drawable/mainpgbg">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_weight="0.50"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:id="@+id/logInBtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I anticipated that the `RelativeLayout` would be displayed centered on the screen, but it seems that you need a `RelativeLayout` to center elements, however you need a `LinearLayout` to create relative size elements.

How can I do both? Center a relatively sized element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to your `LinearLayout`'s xml to **center its children (anything inside of it):**

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="1.0"
android:background="@drawable/mainpgbg"
android:gravity="center">
```

Comment: `android:gravity="center"`

Thank you!!! That worked perfectly, I knew it was something simple I was missing. I didn't realize gravity was to be applied to parents. I had gravity on children.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement your xml is correct, You can also try using TableLayout, 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<!-- 2 columns -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Column 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Column 2" />
</TableRow>

<!-- edittext span 2 column -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
</TableRow>

<!-- just draw a red line -->
<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<!-- 3 columns -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Column 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Column 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Column 3" />
</TableRow>

<!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="Column 3" />
</TableRow>

<!-- display this button in 2nd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Column 2" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thank you ksarmalkar! Much Appreciated!